# Stdout and stderr redirect in windows batch with assoc-command

Tags: windows, batch-file, stdout, stderr

Since `assoc` doesn't correclty manage `%ERRORLEVEL%` I use the following as a workaround:

```
assoc .myext=myext >NUL 2>NUL
ftype myext="%~dp0mybatch.bat" "%%1" >NUL 2>NUL
assoc .myext | find "myext" >NUL 2>NUL
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
    echo Association failed
    goto err
)
ftype otrkey | find "otrmenu" > NUL
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
    echo Association failed
    goto err
)
exit /b 0
:err
exit /b 1
```

I want to keep the output clean because the user don't need the real output from assoc and ftype commands, that's why stdout and stderr are redirected to NUL. The script runs fine but the association doesn't really work. I get a dialog window for an unknown file extention if I try to open a .myext file.

If I remove output redirects from my batch, the association works. How to fix that issue?

**update**: to be precise I can let all the redirects where they are but need to remove *both* redirects from the first line - `assoc .myext=myext` - to make it work.

Comment: Why are you escaping the pipeline?

Comment: Initially I though pipeline would solve the real issue but I didn't. I noticed the pipeline is not the reason for that issue at all. So please review the edited question.

Comment: Try removing the redirects one-by-one and see which causes the error.

Comment: Redirects from the first line are responsible for the issue.

Comment: What is the result if you redirect into a file rather than NUL?

Comment: Since it's the first line you could also not redirect it but call `cls` immediately after it.

Comment: @Liturgist the output is as expected: `stdout.txt: .otrkey=otrkey\r\n`, `stderr.txt: empty`

Comment: @DennisvanGils that's a good workaround, thanks!.. but not the real answer why it doesn't work.

Comment: The standard way to redirect both stdout and stderr to nul is: `command > NUL 2>&1`. Try it

Comment: Wrap the command in a FOR /F and set flag variables.

Comment: Have you tried `assoc ".myext=myext" >NUL 2>NUL`, so with double quotes?

Comment: What do you mean by _"`assoc` doesn't correclty manage `%ERRORLEVEL%`"_?